# Call chartjs in rhino using java

Tags: java, chart.js, rhino

I'm trying to use Chart.js to generate bar chart from java using Rhino to call the function, but I'm having problems with the html elements that Chart.js need. 
How can return the byte array that represent the image generated from chart.js without use html? I know that chart.js use a `<canvas>` but I don't have DOM elements in server side.
I need to use Chart.js from Java, How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's seem not possible to export chart with rhino and chartjs at server side. Please correct me if i am wrong.

But i found few alternate solutions:

- Phantomjs
- Chrome,Mozilla headless
- Nodejs
- JavaFX Webview (seem available on client and not stable on server, unix might not support)

I also tried with :

- htmlunit library
- jsdom, canvas and combine with nashorn.

but All seem not working stable with chartjs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific issues regarding HtmlUnit please open an issue.

https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues